# Is there a way to filter between two data rows in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I came across a problem that I have in my code. In this code below I am trying to print out and list of flight numbers, destination, departure, and arrival times but I'm also trying to filter between two airport codes: origin airports and destination airports.

I ran into a problem of not knowing how to filter between the two codes. Is there a way to do this in python if there is how do I do that?

```
def flights_from():
    # list of flights for the flights.
    # list of airport nodes
    # list of flight numbers, destination, departure and arrival times
    flights = load_flights('flights_01_01.csv')
    for flight in flights: 
        print(
            flight.getOriginairport(),
            flight.getDestinationairport(),
            flight.getFlightnumber(),
            flight.getFlightnumber(),
            flight.getScheduleddeparture(),
            flight.getScheduledarrival()
        )

# here is where I am stuck. Trying to filter between two airport codes.
flights_from()
```

for example, the output for the for loop is

origin airport, destination airports, flight numbers, destination, departure and arrival times

```
SFO, CLT, 840, 840, 20, 806
```

Comment: What do you mean by "filter between the two"? Can you provide a brief example of the contents of `'flights_01_01.csv'` and what the expected output is?

Comment: On an unrelated note; I highly recommend installing black (e.g. `pip install black`). You can then run `black myfile.py` and it will automatically format your code to look nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm also trying to filter between two airport codes: origin airports and destination airports.

If you just want to filter the list based on matching origin and destination, you could do so like this:

```py
def filter_flights(origin, destination):
    flights = load_flights('flights_01_01.csv')
    matching_flights = []
    for flight in flights:
        if (
            flight.getOriginairport() == origin
            and flight.getDestinationairport() == destination
        ): 
            matching_flights.append(flight)
    return matching_flights
```

You could also do this with a list comprehension:

```py
def filter_flights(origin, destination):
    return [
        flight
        for flight in load_flights('flights_01_01.csv')
        if flight.getOriginairport() == origin
        and flight.getDestinationairport() == destination
    ]
```

Comment: Sorry that I can't upvote you yet because I am a new member but It works perfectly.

Comment: @bankoleAdegboye No worries! Happy it's working for you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this.
I am not very sure of it myself because I don't know how does your file looks like.

```
import csv
with open('flights_01_01.csv', newline='') as flight_list:
    flights = csv.DictReader(flight_list)
    for flight in flights:
        print(flight['OriginAirport'], flight['DestinationAirport'])
```